# setData undefined on touching gestures using drag and drop plugin (but works on desktop Chrome)

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, drag-and-drop, data-transfer

I am currently fighting to get drag and drop functionallity on mobile devices. Luckily I found a fitting solution [here](https://github.com/Gmfholley/quickdroppable). The problem that I am still having is this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined
```

This error appears only if I use the mobile mode in chromes dev mode (pressing F12). On normal mode, the code works and the 'setData' gets recognized

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            for(var i=1;i<=12;i++) {
                $('#img' + i).quickdroppable('draggable', {}, function (ev) {
                    ev.dataTransfer.setData("src", ev.target.id);
                    var number = ev.target.id.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
                    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", number);
                });
            }
    })(jQuery);
```

HTML is also not extraordinary:

```
<div>
            <div class="inline-block field" id="preview5" style="margin-bottom:5px" >
                <img class="img-responsive border-blue image-cover" id="img5" src="img/cubthumbs/cub5.jpg" />
            </div><br>
            <?php for($i=4;$i>=1;$i--):?>
                <div class="inline-block field" id="preview<?php echo $i?>" >
                    <img class="img-responsive border-blue image-cover" id="img<?php echo $i?>" src="<?php echo 'img/cubthumbs/cub'.$i.'.jpg';?>"/>
                </div>
            <?php endfor; ?><br>
            <div class="inline-block field" id="preview6">
                <img class="img-responsive border-blue image-cover" id="img6" src="img/cubthumbs/cub6.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Maybe someone had experienced a similiar issue with this using mobile features...

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Yash Unfortunately this solution was limited. It may mimic the drag and drop on touch, but setdata and getdata not.